# How do I properly install Anaconda after uninstalling it?

Tags: python, anaconda

For the past few months Anaconda (2019 Octobre version) has been buggin me to update to the latest version. In my windows 10 Pro (19042.746 build) I have been unsuccesfull to do so in the navigator nor the commandprompt (cmd and git bash).
Today I thought it was time to uninstall Anaconda fully and install it fresh, rather I am out of options and unable to understand what is going wrong. Anaconda is not installing properly on my Windows 10 Pro installation with any version of Anaconda. it only installs:
-conda-meta
-Lib
-pkgs
-.nonadmin
-_conda.exe
-Uninstall-Anaconda3.exe

There is no Anaconda Navigator nor a prompt. I have uninstalled all versions of Python on my computer, removed any references from my path cleaned my /Temp and my cache folders and still I get to this result.

I am currently in the midst of my thesis research and I need Python to run my research. I am currently out of options and I hope someone from your team can help me out with this issue so I can use Anaconda again.

[image]

Comment: good day - many thanks for sharing this question!!

Comment: @zero No worries, do you maybe have a solution to the problem? After backing up my most important files I am going for a full Windows reset. This is kind of my last resort option since I am working against an internal deadline in my project group...